# PhpStorm deployment successful but does not update remote file

Tags: phpstorm, cpanel

I am using a shared hosting platform to host my website and I am using PhpStorm as my IDE.

I have configured PhpStorm for deployment which connects successfully to the server.

When I deploy my file to the server the file transfer terminal shows successful... but if I check the file on the server it is not updated.

[image]

Comment: 1) **Double check** the file paths 2) Make sure that you are using the **correct** Deployment entry (in case if you have more than one). You may simply be uploading this to another server...

Comment: Thanks. I double checked and found out I was uploading to a different folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deployment seems to work fine: if it says uploaded then it did.

You can use "Compare with Deployed..." on such a file (or "Synchronize with Deployed..." on a folder) to see if it will show any differences: if it shows the difference then we have an issue; otherwise it's a misconfiguration somewhere.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/comparing-deployed-files-and-folders-with-their-local-versions.html#compare-local

---

I have seen quite a few PhpStorm tickets/forum treads with similar descriptions... and extremely likely this will be user mistake/misconfiguration.

1. Please double check the file paths (path mappings). *You may be uploading to the wrong folder.*

   Looking at your paths (from your screenshot):

   - source: `C:\xampp\htdocs\agents\application\controllers\Payments.php`
   - target: `/public_html/application/controllers/Payments.php`

   The `agents` must be the project/website name here and you upload from `/agents/application` to `/public_html/application`.

   It's possible (for such controller files at very least) that `/public_html` is not needed here and you may want to upload it into the `/application` folder instead.
2. Make sure that you are using the correct Deployment entry (in case you have more than one). *You may simply be uploading to another/wrong server.*

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with PHPStorm server/deployment settings many times and have encountered several frustrating issues that seem like UX bugs to me. In my latest case, I created a new development server and associated phpstorm project, yet when I deployed files they were going to the production server! After much ado, what finally got the files to deploy to the correct/development server was to set "Mappings"->"Deployment path" from "" to "/". This is an area of PHPStorm that always seems a lot more painful and buggy than it should be. It is the main area of complaint I have with an otherwise really good IDE.  Perhaps this helps others as I arrived here while searching for a solution I ended up having to trip on for myself.